# Indexed (Materialized) View for Parent and Newest Child

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, materialized-view

Say I have parent->child tables setup.  Call them `Shipment` and `Widget`.

Is there anyway to create an Indexed view that will have the PK of the parent (ShipmentId) and the created when of the newest child (Widget.CreatedWhen).

This is the query I am looking for:

```
SELECT  widg.ShipmentId, MAX(widg.CreatedWhen) NewestWidget
FROM    dbo.Widget widg            
GROUP BY widg.ShipmentId
```

Obviously this query cannot be an Indexed View because it has `MAX` in it.

**But is there some other way via "Indexed View Legal" SQL to get a similar result set?**

Comment: You know, [I asked for this support back in 2007](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/267516/expand-aggregate-support-in-indexed-views-min-max), and the request is still active. Aside from maintaining a materialized copy through triggers or similar processes at insert/update time, I don't know of any good workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this currently, as finding the "latest" widget date will require an aggregate (grouping), ranking function, subquery, or apply; none of which the indexed view will allow in its definition.

However - is there a particular reason you want to have an indexed view? Do you have appropriate indexing on the underlying Widget table? I'm assuming that the reason you want to *index* the view is so you can pull out the values for a particular Widget ID.

I would index the underlying table on (WidgetID, CreatedWhen DESC) and implement your query as a normal view - or perhaps a **inline** table valued function if you always want to get the date for a single Widget.